# Render Section Without reloading Layouts MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, layout

I'm using Two layouts 
1-  Main Layout : "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"
2-  Left Side layout "~/Views/Shared/_LeftSide.cshtml" (this view also contains main layout)

In left Side Layout I'm using Render section "Section01"
[image]

After Clicking on 1st link ABC? I've this view with Section01
[image]

But currently its Post Back full page. 
I want to render section without reloading layouts. any body please help, or any other suggestion to achieve this ?

Comment: In `_LeftSide.cshtml` delete the Layout line.

Comment: you need to do an ajax request to your controller that just returns the partial you need

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax request on click of item from left section to load layout 2

```
$.ajax({
          url: '/yoururl/layout2',
          dataType: 'html',
          type: 'GET'
          success: function(data) {
             $('#layout2Div').html(data);
          }
    });
```